# Does [Key] attribute force C# to compare entities by decorated properties?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, comparison, primary-key

```
    public class Potato
    {

        int SomeID { get; set; }
        DataTable Potable { get; set; }
        [Key]
        string PotatoKey { get; set; }
        object GrimReaper { get; set; }
    }
```

When comparing 2 potatoes, does having a [Key] attribute tell C# that in order to do the comparison only PotatoKey  has to be compared? Or do I still need to explicitly tell to compare PotatoKeys?

Comment: If you mean something like `potatoA < potatoB` then you'd need to implement `IComparable<Potato>` then you could call `potatoA.CompareTo(potatoB)`. Alternatively, you could overload the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`,  `>`, and `>=`) in your class and then use `potatoA < potatoB`.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Applying the `==` operator?

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to add custom equals or == != , ... Operators you have to do this completely by hand. Theres no support from C# side. The best I found is "Fody.Equals" that helps you here https://github.com/Fody/Equals. Maybe records can hep you as the have value type comparison, but they compare ALL properties and this is also not changable (easily)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[Key]` does *literally nothing* by itself; it requires other code (usually library code) to check that it exists, and infer some special meaning - presumably "treat this as a primary key" when being handled by some ORM. It doesn't change anything about the C# compiler or any part of the .NET runtime *except* those parts that explicitly check for it. It does not change how object equality or comparison works, for example. There are only a very small handful of attributes that *directly* impact how code behaves.